# Routing Error - Custom Contoller Method (Adding Custom routes in resource routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-routes

I want to add link to friends list but i get routing error

```
No route matches {:action=>"friend_list", :controller=>"users_controller"}
```

users_controller

```
def friend_list
    @frnds =  User.find_friends(current_user)
end
```

routes

```
devise_for :users
resources :users do
member do
  get :follow
  get :unfollow
  get :show
end
match 'users/:id/friend_list' => 'users#friend_list', via: [:get]
```

link

```
<li><%= link_to "Friends",  :controller => :users_controller, :action => :friend_list%></li>
```

end
  match 'users/:id/friend_list' => 'users#friend_list', via: [:get]
  root 'home#front'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of member block use collection block like this

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get "follow"
    get "unfollow"
    get "show"
 end
end
```

member block will append `:id` in routing while collection block will allow you add custom routes in `resource` routes

in link_to use this

```
<%=link_to "Friends", controller: "users", action: "friend_list"%>
```

Comment: what error are you facing can you give me error message what you have?

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"friend_list", :controller=>"users_controller"}

Comment: instead of `users_controller` use only `users` in link_to

Comment: do i need to modify answer?